# Hook Bootstrap Daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am using this template 
http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/index.html

which provides a nice timepicker in the right corner.

However i am unable to submit anything if the user presses the submit button.

This is the library which they use and the exact example 
http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/

how can i submit the picked range if the user clicks on the submit button or any given link like "last 7 days"?

any formsubmit, listener or clickfunction would be fine ... but i dont get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the control has two textboxes, it will update those. However if you want to use that in your application, you can have a textbox (or textboxes) that will be updated by the "onApply" method of the control. In our case we used a 1 textbox and update it with the range.

```
$('#filterDates').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
    try {
        $('#txtStartDate').val(picker.startDate.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
        $('#txtEndDate').val(picker.endDate.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
        //this is what we actually use
        $('#txtFilterDates').val(picker.startDate.format('DD MMM YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
    }
});
```